# Find Click Once Remote Setup location of UNC path NOT local location

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

Okay first off this is NOT 'how do I find my local location of the click once app.'  I know you can go Task Manager>Active Processes>(Find your click once app)>Open File Location.  This is more on how do I know if I have four versions of a click once app for deployemnt of (Dev, QA, UAT, and PROD) how do I know which one has which remote install setup?

EG: So when you deploy a click once you choose a path in VS.  Once you set up the path the user can go to the UNC path and then get their own local click once app, yay.  What happens when this gets junked up?  I just want to know simply:

**How does the click once app reveal to me the local of the remote target in a place I can reference once the app is deployed?**

Like a key pair list or something where I can see:

```
(Program DEV) | \\Devmachine\installs

(Program QA) | \\QAmachine\installs
```

From what I can tell from searching this is not as easy as it sounds to get.  I am up for coding some C# .NET, some command line inputs, or some Windows commands to get to this information.  I just cannot believe something like a target install folder is this hard to get when it is a REQUIREMENT to publish.  The user basically uninstalled the program and naturally it did not remove the Click Once stuff at:

```
C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\LKE4469P.GDW\X7EMR5P8.B1Z\
```

I can find the similar named app folders but their naming does not match up to the manifests.  And even when I look in manifests it appears the info is not there either unless it is in a masked form to decode.

Comment: So you want the path, where each instance (DEV, QA, ...) fetches the updates from?

Comment: Yes, the remote target at the UNC path that the local click once reads from.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ApplicationDeployment.UpdateLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.updatelocation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property gives you the value for the remote location. It can be used like this:

```
// In any class
public static string GetDeploymentPath()
{
    return ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
        ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation
        : String.Empty; // Debug mode
}
```

Comment: Right....  but that looks like you attach that to an existing solution and class. NOT finding existing deployed click once apps on your system judging off of running threads or storage locations.  I was hoping someone knew how to specify a list of apps or target location to then run those DLL's related to click once deployment on.  I already tried these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.activationuri.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.deploymentdownloadexception.aspx

Comment: @djangojazz The only thing I can guess about right now, is to crawl over every computer and search for application manifests. Those hold the URL for the update location.

Comment: They do not store in either the click once manifest nor the *.exe.manifest plain text of location.  It is all 'disgestvalue' and a hash value.  That is why I was hoping there was some way to decrypt this programatically.